# Script runs very slow when changing parameters in Add Object menu

Tags: python, scripting, performance

I've made my first addon based on an internal blender Text editor template. It is used to add primitive meshes and then control some of their aspects, much like adding primitives like Cubes or UV Spheres. The shapes are fairly simple and consist of 16 vertices / 14 faces at most.

However, when changing the parameters in the menu that's shown in the lower left, Blender slows down to the point where it takes a few moments to update to the set value. The more objects already in the scene, the slower it'll go.
There's also a lot of console spam when changing values (though vanilla blender Add Mesh also does this)

Results from running cProfile on the main function:

```
 130 function calls in 0.015 seconds

  Ordered by: standard name

  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1009(_handle_fromlist)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.015 <string>:1(<module>)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 addaprofile.py:16(add_box)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 addaprofile.py:223(execute)
      16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 addaprofile.py:251(<listcomp>)
      11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 bpy_types.py:707(__getattribute__)
       1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 object_utils.py:100(object_data_add)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 object_utils.py:169(align_update_callback)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 object_utils.py:41(add_object_align_init)
       2    0.014    0.007    0.014    0.007 ops.py:155(_view_layer_update)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ops.py:168(__init__)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ops.py:180(idname_py)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.015 ops.py:184(__call__)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ops.py:40(__getattr__)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ops.py:79(__init__)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ops.py:82(__getattr__)
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method Translation}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 {built-in method _bpy.ops.call}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method bmesh.new}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.015 {built-in method builtins.exec}
      21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
       3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
       4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.round}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'ensure_lookup_table' of 'BMVertSeq' objects}
       2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'is_property_set' of 'bpy_struct' objects}
      16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'new' of 'BMFaceSeq' objects}
      16    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'new' of 'BMVertSeq' objects}
      11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'path_resolve' of 'bpy_struct' objects}
       2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'to_4x4' of 'Matrix' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'to_matrix' of 'Euler' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'to_mesh' of 'BMesh' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'to_translation' of 'Matrix' objects}
       1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'zero' of 'Euler' objects}
```

The View layer update seems to take up 14 out of 15 ms total runtime;

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
2       0.014    0.007    0.014    0.007 ops.py:155(_view_layer_update)
```

Considering this and the dependency on the amount of objects in the scene, I would expect this having to do with either updating the view layer too often, or updating too many objects too often.

What can I do to speed up execution of the script, or to reduce the number of view layer updates?

My code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add Profile",
    "author": "x",
    "location": "View3D > Add Mesh",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 81, 16),
    "description": "Quickly add (steel) profiles; rectangular or U-shaped.",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
    }

import bpy
import bmesh
import cProfile
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper

def add_box(width, height, depth, wall_thickness, profileType):
    """
    This function takes inputs and returns vertex and face arrays.
    no actual mesh data creation is done here.
    """
    scaleFactor = 1
    width_m = width / (2 * scaleFactor)
    depth_m = depth / (2 * scaleFactor)
    height_m = height / (1 * scaleFactor)
    thickness_mm = wall_thickness / (2 * scaleFactor)

    wF = (width_m - (2*thickness_mm)) / width_m
    dF = (depth_m - (2*thickness_mm)) / depth_m

    # Profile types: RECT, U_PROF
    if profileType == 'RECT':
        # create square profile with inner vertices at offset size
        verts = [
            (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0), #0 outer edge bottom
            (+1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
            (+1.0, +1.0, 0.0),
            (-1.0, +1.0, 0.0), #3

            (-wF, -dF, 0.0), #4 inner edge bottom
            (+wF, -dF, 0.0),
            (+wF, +dF, 0.0),
            (-wF, +dF, 0.0), #7

            (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0), #8 outer edge top
            (+1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
            (+1.0, +1.0, 1.0),
            (-1.0, +1.0, 1.0), #11

            (-wF, -dF, 1.0), #12 inner edge top
            (+wF, -dF, 1.0),
            (+wF, +dF, 1.0),
            (-wF, +dF, 1.0), #15
        ]

        # create faces between these vertices
        faces = [
            (4, 5, 1, 0), #bottom
            (5, 6, 2, 1),
            (6, 7, 3, 2),
            (7, 4, 0, 3),

            (0, 1, 9, 8), #outside
            (1, 2, 10, 9),
            (2, 3, 11, 10),
            (3, 0, 8, 11),

            (4, 12, 13, 5), #inside
            (5, 13, 14, 6),
            (7, 6, 14, 15),
            (4, 7, 15, 12),

            (8, 9, 13, 12), #top
            (9, 10, 14, 13),
            (10, 11, 15, 14),
            (11, 8, 12, 15),
        ]

    elif profileType == 'U_PROF':
        # create U shaped profile with inner vertices at offset size
        verts = [
            (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0), #0
            (+1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
            (+1.0, +1.0, 0.0),
            (-1.0, +1.0, 0.0), #3

            (-wF, -dF, 0.0), #4
            (+1.0, -dF, 0.0),
            (+1.0, +dF, 0.0),
            (-wF, +dF, 0.0), #7

            (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0), #8 outer edge top
            (+1.0, -1.0, 1.0),
            (+1.0, +1.0, 1.0),
            (-1.0, +1.0, 1.0), #11

            (-wF, -dF, 1.0), #4
            (+1.0, -dF, 1.0),
            (+1.0, +dF, 1.0),
            (-wF, +dF, 1.0), #7
        ]

        # create faces between these vertices
        faces = [
            (4, 5, 1, 0), #bottom
            (6, 7, 3, 2),
            (7, 4, 0, 3),

            (0, 1, 9, 8), #outside
            (3, 0, 8, 11),
            (2, 3, 11, 10),

            (1, 5, 13, 9), #inside
            (5, 4, 12, 13),
            (4, 7, 15, 12),
            (7, 6, 14, 15),
            (6, 2, 10, 14),

            (9, 13, 12, 8), #top
            (11, 8, 12, 15),
            (10, 11, 15, 14)
        ]

    # apply size
    for i, v in enumerate(verts):
        verts[i] = v[0] * width_m, v[1] * depth_m, v[2] * height_m

    return verts, faces

from bpy.props import (
    BoolProperty,
    BoolVectorProperty,
    EnumProperty,
    FloatProperty,
    FloatVectorProperty,
)

class AddBox(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add a Profile mesh"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.primitive_profile_add"
    bl_label = "Add Profile"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    uF = 1000 #unitFactor

    profileTypes = (
        ('RECT', "Rectangular", "Rectangular profile."),
        ('U_PROF', "U-profile", "U-shaped profile.")
    )

    # Select desired profile shape
    profileType: EnumProperty(
        name="Profile type",
        items=profileTypes,
        default='RECT',
    )

    wall_thickness: FloatProperty(
        name="Wall Thickness",
        description="Wall Thickness",
        min=0.001, max=0.02,
        default=0.004,
        unit='LENGTH',
    )

    width: FloatProperty(
        name="Width (X)",
        description="Profile Width",
        min=0.001, max=0.5,
        default=0.06,
        unit='LENGTH',
    )

    depth: FloatProperty(
        name="Depth (Y)",
        description="Profile Depth",
        min=0.001, max=0.5,
        default=0.06,
        unit='LENGTH',
    )

    height: FloatProperty(
        name="Height (Z)",
        description="Profile Height",
        min=0.001, max=5,
        default=1,
        unit='LENGTH',
    )

    layers: BoolVectorProperty(
        name="Layers",
        description="Object Layers",
        size=20,
        options={'HIDDEN', 'SKIP_SAVE'},
    )

    # generic transform props
    align_items = (
        ('WORLD', "World", "Align the new object to the world"),
        ('VIEW', "View", "Align the new object to the view"),
        ('CURSOR', "3D Cursor", "Use the 3D cursor orientation for the new object")
    )

    align: EnumProperty(
        name="Align",
        items=align_items,
        default='WORLD',
        update=AddObjectHelper.align_update_callback,
        options={'HIDDEN'},
    )

    location: FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Location",
        subtype='TRANSLATION',
        options={'HIDDEN'},
    )
    rotation: FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Rotation",
        subtype='EULER',
        options={'HIDDEN'},
    )


    def execute(self, context):
        vertex_locations, faces = add_box(
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.depth,
            self.wall_thickness,
            self.profileType,
        )
        nWi = str(round((self.width * 1000)))
        nHe = str(round((self.height * 1000)))
        nDe = str(round((self.depth * 1000)))
        nWT = str(round((self.wall_thickness * 1000)))
        type = str(self.profileType)

        # profileType width x depth x height nWTmm
        name = type + " " + nWi + "x" + nDe + "x" + nHe + ", " + nWT + "mm"

        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
        bm = bmesh.new()

        # create vertices at specified coordinates
        for vertex_coordinates in vertex_locations:
            bm.verts.new(vertex_coordinates)

        bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

        # create faces from previously added vertices
        for face_index in faces:
            bm.faces.new([bm.verts[i] for i in face_index])

        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
        mesh.update()
        # add the mesh as an object into the scene with this utility module
        from bpy_extras import object_utils
        object_utils.object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(AddBox.bl_idname, icon='FACE_MAPS')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddBox)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddBox)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Will find `Mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)` is quicker than bmesh.  `Mesh.update()` is probably handled by add object helper method.  String formatting is quicker than concatenating.  Would also subclass the `AddObjectHelper` class and remove need to redefine location, rotation and align.

Comment: @batFINGER could you perhaps explain this a bit more? I'm fairly new to coding/python and I'm not sure how to implement any of this.